# How to get Excel to change dot for colon when entering time value, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The code is for a timesheet that is idiot proof.

For example;

- Entering 0845 changes to the correct time format of 08:45
- Entering 8:45 changes to the correct time format of 08:45
- Entering 845 changes to the correct time format of 08:45
- Entering an incorrect time value, for example 08:75 a message box appears "you did not enter a valid time" and changes the value back to 00:00

The above all works correctly.

My question is, how can I get it to change a '.' for a ':' if for example someone enters 08.45 instead of 08:45.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TimeStr As String

On Error GoTo EndMacro

If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B5:AC126")) Is Nothing Then

Exit Sub

End If

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then

Exit Sub

End If

If Target.Value = "" Or Target.Value < 1 Then

Exit Sub

End If

Application.EnableEvents = False

With Target

If .HasFormula = False Then

Select Case Len(.Value)

Case 1 ' e.g., 1 = 01:00 AM

TimeStr = Left(.Value, 1) & ":00"

Case 2 ' e.g., 12 = 12:00 AM

TimeStr = Left(.Value, 2) & ":00"

Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 7:35 AM

TimeStr = Left(.Value, 1) & ":" & _

Right(.Value, 2)

Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12:34

TimeStr = Left(.Value, 2) & ":" & _

Right(.Value, 2)

Case 5 ' e.g., 12345 = 1:23:45 NOT 12:03:45

TimeStr = Left(.Value, 1) & ":" & _

Mid(.Value, 2, 2) & ":" & Right(.Value, 2)

Case 6 ' e.g., 123456 = 12:34:56

TimeStr = Left(.Value, 2) & ":" & _

Mid(.Value, 3, 2) & ":" & Right(.Value, 2)

Case Else

Err.Raise 0

End Select

.Value = TimeValue(TimeStr)

End If

End With

Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

EndMacro:

    If Not (IsDate(MyDate)) Then

        MsgBox "You did not enter a valid time"

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are having those kinds of problems with your users, I suggest you develop a User Form which controls the data entry process, rather than trying to correct it after the fact.

Comment: I guess the first step is to precisely which input is "allowed" and how is it interpreted? Is `775` supposed to be 7:45? With the same logic `730` would be 7:18. Is 7.25 to be seen as 7:15? Is `7,25` also allowed?

Comment: Similar to FunThomas' question, is `.5` entered equivalent to `00:30`?  I cannot upvote Ron's comment enough... Unless you want to handle the hassle, you will want to give fields to control, e.g., a field for the hour and a field for the fraction of an hour or actual minutes, so there is no question about what is being entered in each.  The aspect of using a Userform is more ideal than a simple input box because you can request information be split, rather than running substitution/replace/etc. on a single string to get it to the style you desire.

Comment: So the allowed input should be between 700 to 759 and be seen as 07:00 to 07:59. Which is what the code currently does. However if 760 to 799 in entered then a error message should be displayed and the value set to 00:00.

Comment: Similarly, if 7.60 to 7.99 is entered this should show an error message and the value set to 00:00. 

.5 is seen as 50 minutes instead of 30 minutes.

Comment: For the most part the code works but trying to eliminate all human error, for example if something enters 7:75 instead of 7:45 by mistake, error message appears to inform them and resets value to 00:00.

Comment: So you don't actually need the "7" in your information, only the minutes (0-60)?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I have reworded the question because I realised it was confusing and the issue I'm having was not clear, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Scott use [`Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is as straight forward as a person putting a numeric value between zero and sixty, here is a mock-up to get you started (untested):

```
sub thisSubRoutine()
thisSubRoutine_restart():
    dim inputValue as long
    inputValue = inputbox("Enter minutes for hour of 0700 between 0 and 60")
    if inputValue > 60 or inputValue < 0 or isnumeric(inputValue) = false then
        msgbox "Invalid entry"
        goto thisSubRoutine_restart
    end if
    'Do something with the data
end sub
```

This makes the entire subroutine based on error handling, where it restarts the subroutine after messaging the user that an incorrect value was entered.

---

Updating with new answer...

Use `Replace(yourString, ":", ".")`, e.g.,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I have reworded the question because I realised it was confusing and the issue I'm having was not clear, hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: @Scott updated answer.  Note that you can loop through an array of potential options to replace in the second argument, which may help if you've got several items that need to be changed to a decimal.